# how to get the id attribute of <td> from <tr> in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me with this.

instead of looping for  ..do we have anything like get the id of first td or second one ?

example :

```
"<tr class='test_point' id="+fileName+"><td><img src='"+ROOT_PATH+"/assets/diamond.png' /><td class='test_point_name' id="+test_point_id+">"+test_point

+"</td></tr>"
```

fetching the tr by ID here

```
$(#fileName).each(function( index ){
  console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
  //console.log("id_value: "+$(this).attr('id'));
  console.log("test_value: "+ $(this).find('td').attr('id'))
}
```

Comment: `$(#fileName).find('td').each(function( index ){` you forgot `.find('td')` or use `.children('td')`

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID? You have no quotation marks around your selector? You have no closing `)`? Are you getting any output?

Comment: are you wrapping your code with `<table>`? without it nothing will get it work. check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rgNP7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `id` of an item by its *index*, use this.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rgNP7/)**

```
$('#fileName').find('td')[0].id;
```

Where `[0]` means first, `[1]` second...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for the `each` statement is a bit off. You're missing quotes:

```
$("#fileName").each(function( index ){
```

Or maybe you wanted to use the variable `fileName`

```
$("#" + fileName).each(function( index ){
```

In any case, ID's should be unique. Im guessing you want to use your `tr`s class:

```
$(".test_point").each(function( index ){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your-tr-id-here').each(function() {
    $(this).children('td').each(function() {
        console.log('td ID: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```